# What are the favorite interpretations of quantum mechanics by the recent Nobel laureates in physics?

Tags: physics, quantum-mechanics

The new Nobel laureates in physics have been given the prize because of their contributions to quantum mechanics (QM).

Of course, the Nobel prize focusses more on groundbreaking work that has links to applications and experiments, rather than on purely theoretical foundational questions.

Still, it would be interesting to know what the new Nobels think about the foundations of their field, especially considering the renaissance that foundational questions in QM seem to have enjoyed 'recently'.

Comment: This doesn't look like a question about History.

Comment: By "new" you mean Aspect, Clauser and Zeilinger? Penrose, for example, who got the prize in 2020, has a famously [kooky interpretation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orchestrated_objective_reduction#Background), a version of objective collapse that involves quantum gravity, "Platonic information" and consciousness.

Comment: @Conifold: yes I meant the most recent ones.

Comment: @José Carlos Santos: wonderful, so my question got rejected at the physics SE site and I was suggested to post it here, and here it's not historical enough. Well, I guess it doesn't fit into any existing SE site then. It happens... :)

Comment: Alain Aspect, at least, never stroke me as interested in this topic. I tried once to ask him about this, and he mostly swept the question aside, explaining that he was happy focusing on what he could observe and measure.

Comment: Here is an essay on interpretations from Zeilinger: http://fisica.ugto.mx/~gniz/courses/mec_cuan_01_15/Zeilinger.pdf